# how do I pass a database NULL value to a string variable?

Tags: c#, sql

Basically if a parameter comes in as NULL, I want to send it to the database as a database NULL. As such (look at the comment inside the code below):

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UpdateTitle(Title title)
    {
      string query = null;
      string description = "";
      string episodeAKA = "";

      if (title.Description != null)
      {
        description = "'" + title.Description + "'";
      }
      else
      {
        //here's where description should be a DBNULL. 
      }

      if (title.EpisodeAKA == null)
      {
        title.EpisodeAKA = "NULL";
      }

      myConnection.Open();
      if (title.Operation == 'U')
      {
        query = "UPDATE dbo.AWD_Titles SET AwardStatusId = " + title.AwardStatus + ", Description = " + description + ", IsVerified = " + title.IsVerified + ", EpisodeAKA = '" + title.EpisodeAKA + "' WHERE AwardTitleId = " + title.AwardTitleId + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
      }
      var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
      cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      myConnection.Close();
    }
  }
```

And here's the class for Title:

```
public class Title
{
  public int AwardTitleId
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public int AwardStatus
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public int IsVerified
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string EpisodeAKA
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Description
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public char Operation
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. That is **really bad**; it's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Or just use the ORM of your choice..

Comment: Also, if the query throws an exception, you'll start leaving connections hanging open and eventually lock yourself out of the database. With a shared connection object, you may also leave that object in an unusable state, thus locking yourself out even sooner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original code had several fundamental errors. This demonstrates how to do it *right*, including how to set DBNull:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateTitle(Title title)
{
    string query; 
    if (title.Operation == 'U')
    {
        query = 
            "UPDATE dbo.AWD_Titles" + 
            " SET AwardStatusId = @AwardStatusID , Description = @Description , IsVerified= @IsVerified , EpisodeAKA= @EpisodeAKA" + 
            " WHERE AwardTitleId= @AwardTitleId ;" + 
            " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    } else {
       query="";
       //presumably you have a slightly different query string for inserts.
       //Thankfully, they should have pretty much the same set of parameters.
       //If this method will really only be called for updates, the code is quite a bit simpler
    }

    //instead of a shared myConnection object, use a shared connection string.
    // .Net is set up so that you should be creating a new connection object for most queries.
    // I know it sounds backwards, but that's really the right way to do it.
    // Create the connection in a using(){} block, so that you guarantee it is
    //    disposed correctly, even if an exception is thrown.
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        //guessing at database types, lengths here. Fix with actual column types
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AwardStatusId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = title.AwardStatus;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = title.Description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsVerified", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = title.IsVerified;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EpisodeAKA", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = title.EpisodeAKA;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AwardTitleId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = title.AwardTitleId;

        //-------------
        //This is the part that actually answers your question
        foreach (var p in cmd.Parameters.Where(p => p.Value == null))
        {
            p.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        //-------------

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the code that you have, you could just use `null` in the SQL code:

```
description = "null";
```

However, you should really use a parameterised query instead of concatenating values into the SQL code. If any of the data comes from user input, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

For a parameter value you use `DBNull.Value` for a null value, so the variable holding it has to be an object:

```
object description;

if (title.Description != null) {
  description = title.Description;
} else {
  description = DBNull.Value; 
}
```

Now you can use that value in an `SqlParameter` object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first. Your code is asking for a SQL injection attack. Use [parameterized  queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Unto the question itself. You need to pass the value DBNull.Value if what you want is a data base NULL. You could use a helper function that *converts* your string to the appropriate value.

```
private object ConvertToDbReadyString(string value)
{
    if(value=="NULL")
        return DBNull.Value;
    else
        return value;
}
```

Comment: Hm... What if someone actually wants to store the text "NULL" in a field...?

Comment: @Guffa - I guess the OP would need to change his requirements then :)

Comment: What requirement are you talking about?

Comment: From the OP "Basically if a parameter comes in as NULL, I want to send it to the database as a database NULL"

Comment: I think that by NULL the op means NULL, not "NULL".

Comment: I interpreted that way because of this line "title.EpisodeAKA = "NULL"". I could be wrong of course. So if the OP can weigh in on this I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (title.Description != null)
      {
        description = "'" + title.Description + "'";
      }
      else
      {
        //here's where description should be a DBNULL. 
      }
```

try this one:

```
description = title.Description ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Using an empty string for the value will cause a syntax error in the SQL code. You can use `"null"` instead of `string.Empty` and it will work, but concatenating values into the SQL code is not really a good idea.

Comment: @Guffa may be use description = title.Description ?? ''; but it's not so nice)

Comment: That's also an empty string, so it gives the same syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
string variableValue == string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) ? null : "Hello";
```